# Missing default categories and custom taxonomies in wordpress dashboard

Tags: wordpress, categories, dashboard

Recently I migrated my website to VPS and it worked fine for few days, after that somehow I found all the categories and custom taxonomies were gone. Although it shows n number of items in categories section but the message displayed is No items found.

Please check this dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39933074/category-error.png

Any help will really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the MySQL server. I ran into this same issue today and it took a while to find the solution. I tried several other suggestions like repairing the database. I noticed a few other weird issues with the site. I came across a 2 year old link on the Wordpress forums and further down in the thread it mentions restarting the mysql server. That worked. Fixed the problem instantly.